Derivative convergence rate from uniform convergence
Let $F_n: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a sequence of infinitely differentiable functions that converges pointwise to $F: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, which is also infinitely differentiable. Suppose that $\alpha, \beta >0$ satisfy:
$$ \max_{-1 \le t \le 1} |F_n(t) - F(t)| \le \alpha \cdot n^\beta $$
Then for each integer $k>0$, can we find $\alpha_k, \beta_k > 0$ such that the following holds?
$$ \bigg| \bigg(\frac{\text d}{\text d t}\bigg)^k_{t=0} \big( F_n(t) - F(t) \big) \bigg| \le \alpha_k \cdot n^{\beta_k}$$
I want $\alpha_k, \beta_k$ to be simple expressions depending only on $\alpha, \beta, k$.
Remark.
I'm thinking that Finite Difference Coefficients might be a way to achieve bounds like this, but I'm not sure if this is an overkill.
Also, it's sufficient for my purposes to assume that $F_n, F$ are all real analytic functions.

Do you want exact equality on the second equation, not inequality? I don't think it is likely to have something like that by only assuming sup norm of $F_n  - F$ is given, since you can simply change the derivative a bit but still keep the same sup norm.

okay, that was silly. I meant <= not =. Edited the question!

Let $F = 0$ and
$$
F_n(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sin(g(n)t)
$$
where $g(n)$ is any function that grows faster than polynomials.
Then you can uniformly take $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 0$, but
$$
\Bigg|\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^{2m+1}_{t=0} F_{n}(t)\Bigg| = \frac{1}{n}g(n)^{2m+1} |\cos (n^n t)|_{t=0} = \frac{1}{n}g(n)^{2m+1}
$$
grows much faster than polynomials in $n$.
I wonder if the statement would be true if one also assumes the derivatives of $F_{n}$ converges to derivatives of $F$ in any sense.

Edited: thanks @Goncalo for pointing out the error!

$\sin(n^nt)$ does not converge pointwise to $0$.

@Gonçalo Thanks, it is fixed.
